# Generated objects are not interactive in a canvas

Tags: reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

The code below creates a canvas with a button that runs a function to add an object (rectangle) inside the canvas, the object is added successfully.

However, the rectangle is not interactive/not movable.

In previous attempts I hard-coded (not with a function executed with an `onClick`) the rectangle inside the canvas which worked, and it was interactive, so its not a matter of library or packages.

```js
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

function App() {
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);

  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      backgroundColor: "#45F19C"
    })
  )

  const addRect = () => {
    if (canvas) {
      const rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 50,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: "red",
        selectable: true,
        hasControls: true,
      });
      canvas.add(rect);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const newCanvas = initCanvas();
    setCanvas(newCanvas);

    newCanvas.lowerCanvasEl.style.userSelect = "none";
    
    newCanvas.on("object:moving", (options) => {
      const obj = options.target;

      if (obj.left < 0) {
        obj.left = 0;
      }
      if (obj.top < 0) {
        obj.top = 0;
      }
      if (obj.left + obj.width * obj.scaleX > newCanvas.width) {
        obj.left = newCanvas.width - obj.width * obj.scaleX;
      }
      if (obj.top + obj.height * obj.scaleY > newCanvas.height) {
        obj.top = newCanvas.height - obj.height * obj.scaleY;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addRect}>Add</button>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note: when I hardcoded `const rect = new fabric.Rect()`, it moved inside `useEffect`.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `<StrictMode>` tags in the `index.js` file are interfering with the library. After removing the tags, it works perfectly.